# Return back to previous previous activity

Tags: android, android-activity

Here is what the structure looks like:

Activity 1/2/3 -> Activity 4 -> Activity 5

On Act4, if a boolean variable is true, it jumps straight to Act5.
My problem is that when I press back on Act5, i want to get back to the activity which called Act4. But what happens is that it jumps back to Act5. If i use intent on back press, I i wouldn't know which activity called Act4.

in onCreate of Act4, i have this code:

```
if (boolean) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Act5.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Is it okay to call finish first before the startActivity?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you finished Activity `Act4` after moving to Activity `Act5`?

Comment: yes. on Act4, i called finish after calling startActivity to start Act5.

Comment: paste the relevant code

Comment: relevant code, you mean the intents and finish? plus on super.onbackpressed?

Comment: onResume() and onCreate() or onBackPressed()....? of activity(s), where the boolean is checked would help, it seems that the boolean variable which is true is not being passed as false and the one time action, jumping to Act5 is repeated after pressing back from Act5

Comment: inside your if condition, should set the "mApplication.areMealPlanDatesSet()" as false

Comment: Is it okay to call finish first before the startActivity?

Comment: Sorry, I re-edited it. I can't do that because it will not go as it needs to go on the next run.

Comment: want in previous activity from back press of device navigation back button???

Comment: I'm really sorry but I don't understand.

Comment: So, what was the downvote for?

Answer (score 0):

Before calling intent to start act5 from act4 call finish() method.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean your_variable = true;

if(your_variable)
{
   startActivity(new Intent(Act4.this, Act5.class));

   finish();//now this finish() method will finish Act4 so when you press back on Act5 it will return back to Act3

}
```

Comment: exactly what i did. even added FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP to try if it'll work, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

My Suggestion is to use `startActivityForResult()` instead of `startActivity(intent)` and when you finish from activity5, you can set some flag and can manage while reaching `onActivityResult()`

if you want to finish activity4 based on flag, do `finish()` in `onActivityResult()`

Comment: so i should set onactivityresult on Act4, right? but isn't oncreate called before onactivityresult?

Comment: No in usual scenario, but will call when app goes in background and loss the memory. You can check it in oncreate by checking the bundle null or not, You can preserve value in onSavedInstanceState()

Answer (score 0):

in onCreate method of your Act4 class you can put

```
if (yourBooleanValue) {
    finish();
    startActivity(yourIntent);
}
```

or, it would be better if you would have that boolean in your 3rd activity..

Comment: Act 1-3 are different activities which can call Act4.

Comment: Is it okay to call finish first before the startActivity?

Comment: it is ok to call finish() method before startActivity().

your code also works when i try it without setFlags() method. i think you shouldn't use "intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);"

Answer (score 0):

you can manage by passing some value by putExtra  by activity 1/2/3 and on activity 5 you can go back to activity according to those values.